# Android lib Admob Not enough space to show ad for tablet

Tags: java, android, admob, google-dfp, temenos-quantum

i am building an android lib with AdMob to use on kony platform. The lib works great for a android phone or for tablets which are in portrait mode by default, but the Ad doesn't display on the galaxy Tab 10.1 (which is a in landscape by default).

i get this error :

```
Not enough space to show ad. Needs 1280x90 dp, but only has 800x1207 dp.
```

it seems that Admob get the size in landscape mode instead of the portrait size.  (to be clear, portrait being 800x1207 and landscape 1280x800 when a write about it) and i am not sure where does the issue com from

my application is portrait mode only and i use this code to create my banner :

```
public View onCreateView(Context context) {

        adView = new PublisherAdView(context);
        adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
        adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        /*LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adView.setLayoutParams(lparams);*/

        PublisherAdRequest.Builder publisherAdRequestBuilder = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder();

        // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
        publisherAdRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXX");
        adView.loadAd(publisherAdRequestBuilder.build());
        return adView;
    }
```

onCreateView is call by the kony platform to display the Ad and I don't really know what's happen on this side. This code works fine for any android phone and tablet which are in portrait mode by default.

i can also display an Ad on the galaxy 10.1 if I change SMART_BANNER by Leaderboard but it's not centered on the Kony app and not as convenient as the smart banner.

I don't know android a lot and might have forgot to check something basic. 
is there anything i could try to get the correct size before to investigate if it comes from Kony?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your layout for any padding. It just works if you remove any default padding.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't have any padding. For now, i am just displaying the leaderboard instead of the smart banner when it's a landscape tablet

Comment: How is your layout xml, if any? Can you post it?